# ERROR PRIVILEGES WITH SELECT INTO FILE ... ON MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Am trying to perform a select into outfile, am having following errors

My request:

```
SELECT * INTO OUTFILE '/local/home/datawords/upload/inscrit_newsletter_us.csv'
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM newsletter_us;
```

Error:

> ERROR 1 (HY000): Can't create/write to file '/local/home/datawords/upload/exports/inscrit_newsletter_us.csv' (Errcode: 2)

The exports directory have permission set to 0777.

Comment: I bet you have either `AppArmour` or `SELinux` running. Try to export to the MySQL data directory - if this works, this should be proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate this file in /tmp folder if it has root permissions

For ex `select * into OUTFILE /tmp/inscrit_newsletter_us.csv`

If you dont have root permission for /tmp folder means please follow the below steps

```
sudo chown root:root /tmp
sudo chmod 1777 /tmp
sudo /etc/init.d/mysqld restart
```

Comment: thank you. file created. i can't see it via winscp in grapical mode !

Answer (score 0):

From [the documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/privileges-provided.html):

> **The `FILE` privilege gives you permission to read and write files on the
>   server host using the `LOAD DATA INFILE` and `SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE`
>   statements and the `LOAD_FILE()` function.** A user who has the `FILE`
>   privilege can read any file on the server host that is either
>   world-readable or readable by the MySQL server. (This implies the user
>   can read any file in any database directory, because the server can
>   access any of those files.) **The `FILE` privilege also enables the user
>   to create new files in any directory where the MySQL server has write
>   access.** As a security measure, the server will not overwrite existing
>   files.

Ensure that your user has that privilege.

Then check that the target directory permissions match the above requirements.